# Proper sorting of groups that begin with a person's name

Tags: names, sort-ordering

If I were sorting, for example, audio recordings based upon the performer, then "Vince Guaraldi" and "Bob Seger" would be sorted as "Guaraldi, Vince" and "Seger, Bob"

On the other hand it's not immediately clear to me how I should sort a recording by "Vince Guaraldi Trio" or "Bob Seger & The Silver Bullet Band."  My instinct is that this is now an entire proper name for a group and shouldn't be split up (just like I wouldn't sort things under "Zeppelin, Led"), but in both cases the group name is created to highlight the most famous member.

Both of my print style-guides are silent on this; the [MusicBrainz style guide](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Style/Artist/Sort_Name), is clear that e.g. "Guaraldi, Vince, Trio" is correct, but I'm not sure if that's just a quirk of a single site, or if it is something more universally done.

Comment: If this is a list like an index, I would expect the band names to be listed in their alphabetical order, so "Vince Guaraldi Trio" listed like that under V.

Comment: As a library cataloguer, this sort of thing used to be my bread and butter, but I've been retired over 10 years and can't remember the rules for group names like this (music cataloguing was only a small part of my work). The MusicBrainz guide seems sensible enough to me.